# why liquibase append new changes to the exisiting content of diffChangelog?

Tags: java, database, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I am using Liquibase Hibernate extension to generate diffChangeLogFile against my database  and my model.The problem is when I run it with maven and there is some changes in the model, Liquibase append the generated ChangeSets to the old diffChangeLogFile content so I get a lot of repeated ChangSets, not with the same id but with the same content.
I know it will not be a problem for update because Liquibase will skip repeated changeSets but I want  that everytime I run maven diff goal, Liquibase erase the old content of my diffChangeLogFile and put the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is basically the purpose of the diff command. If you want to generate a new change log, you should be using the generateChangeLog command.

Comment: another question plz : when using Liquibase with java how can i pass an inputStream  or a string instead of a changelogfile path in the update method ?  is that possible ?

Comment: You would probably need to write your own 'integration' classes to be able to do that. I don't think there is a way to do that using the existing integrations (i.e. command line, maven, etc.)

Also, Liquibase identifies changesets with three values - the id, author, and path. So if you have two changesets that are 'functionally equivalent' but have different ids, you will have problems deploying them.